# How to collect a loss from all GPU's when using DistributedDataParallel

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, loss

I implemented parallelized training, but I don't know how to collect losses from each video card and summarize the output loss in a general way.

I think it is necessary to explain that the task is more abstract than I presented in the code. In general, my task is to make DDP mode work for any model. That is, I will receive a model, an optimizer, a learning rate and everything else that is required for full-fledged training, then I will transfer the model to DDP mode and collect loss from all GPUs that are at my disposal.

My code:

```
import torch
import torch.distributed as dist
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.multiprocessing as mp

from torch.nn.parallel import DistributedDataParallel as DDP


def setup(rank, world_size):
    os.environ['MASTER_ADDR'] = 'localhost'
    os.environ['MASTER_PORT'] = '12355'

    # initialize the process group
    dist.init_process_group("gloo", rank=rank, world_size=world_size)


def cleanup():
    dist.destroy_process_group()


def run_demo(demo_fn, world_size):
    mp.spawn(demo_fn,
             args=(world_size,),
             nprocs=world_size,
             join=True)


class ToyMpModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, dev0, dev1):
        super(ToyMpModel, self).__init__()
        self.dev0 = dev0
        self.dev1 = dev1
        self.net1 = torch.nn.Linear(10, 10).to(dev0)
        self.relu = torch.nn.ReLU()
        self.net2 = torch.nn.Linear(10, 5).to(dev1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.to(self.dev0)
        x = self.relu(self.net1(x))
        x = x.to(self.dev1)
        return self.net2(x)


def demo_model_parallel(rank, world_size):
    print(f"Running DDP with model parallel example on rank {rank}.")
    setup(rank, world_size)

    # setup mp_model and devices for this process
    dev0 = (rank * 2) % world_size
    dev1 = (rank * 2 + 1) % world_size
    mp_model = ToyMpModel(dev0, dev1)
    ddp_mp_model = DDP(mp_model)

    loss_fn = nn.MSELoss()
    optimizer = optim.SGD(ddp_mp_model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

    optimizer.zero_grad()
    # outputs will be on dev1
    outputs = ddp_mp_model(torch.randn(20, 10))
    labels = torch.randn(20, 5).to(dev1)
    loss_fn(outputs, labels).backward()
    optimizer.step()

    cleanup()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n_gpus = torch.cuda.device_count()
    assert n_gpus >= 2, f"Requires at least 2 GPUs to run, but got {n_gpus}"
    world_size = n_gpus
    run_demo(demo_model_parallel, world_size)
```